# C-statistic with censoring data

Tags: r, survival, stata, censoring, epidemiology

I have analyzed a cancer dataset that contains risk factors and an outcome. However, I am dealing with many observations lost to follow-up and missing values.  
I want to obtain the c-statistic, but I was told that the c-statistic can be biased in the presence of censoring data and recommended me to use the Uno c-statistic (available in R).

Currently, I am using Stata and mentions that the Gonen and Heller estimate is better in case of censoring data.

Which method is better? The Gonen/Heller or the Uno c-statistics?

Many thanks